# 'Login' form not accessing user database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, authentication

I am trying to build a very simple user authentication for my application. I think the problem is that the 'login' form is not pointing to the :user database. When I create a new user, I have it set to auto-login. That function works great, but when I go to login the same user in the login form, it returns an error of "username is NULL LIMIT 1. I am using Rails 4.2.5 . When I go to the rails console, I can see that the user still exists.

I apologize in advance for my horrible coding habits, I've mostly been teaching myself. Thank you in advance for any help.

Sessions Controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

   def new

    end

   def create

    user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:username][:password])

      session[:user_id] = user.id

      redirect_to root_path, notice: "You are now logged in."

    else 

      redirect_to '/login', notice: "incorrect email or password! "

    end

   end

    def destroy

      session[:user_id] = nil

      redirect_to root_path, notice: "logged out."

    end

end
```

User Model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_secure_password
 validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email
 validates :password, length: {minimum: 6}, allow_blank: true
 has_many :messages
end
```

Login Form

```
<div class="login">
<%= simple_form_for :sessions do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Login" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

When I attempt to login, the terminal returns:

> Started POST "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-06-02 00:02:15 -0400
>   Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
>     Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WNJziVL/xhAeGdsjNANi6LWlDrAMIGKm2kDWmsVLfxMh6fCwG1LoRWG09wgsn2z3rIZkreODkHZ0GJeYFCW3yQ==", "sessions"=>{"username"=>"crackerjack540", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Login"}
>     User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 1
>   Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login
>   Completed 302 Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

Comment: A tip: storing user_id in session is not secure, because it can be stolen and reused. You should generate a new session token with each login and store that instead.

Comment: Will do. I appreciate the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Username is within the session object, so instead of this:

```
user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
```

You should be doing this:

```
user = User.find_by_username(params[:sessions][:username])
```

Also, further below, to access the password:

```
user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much, but now it says "username = ?" instead of "Username is NULL".

Comment: Make sure you get the right username when you  access params[:sessions][:username] (try outputting the value yourself to double check)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked out. I had to add a new user to the database, and now it works like a charm.